# Explicit form of the wavefunctional

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, wavefunction, field-theory

In quantum mechanics, one in principle can write down an explicit form of the corresponding wave-function. For example, $V_i$ for the $i$-th level of quantum harmonic oscillator.

In QFT, the Hilbert space which the quantum fields act on is not the space of wave-functions, but rather of functionals on the space of field configurations. Is it possible to *explicitly* write down those functionals and the corresponding field configurations for $0, 1, 2, \ldots$ excitations (particles) of the field?

And I don't mean things like $a^\dagger_p a^\dagger_q|\mathrm{vacuum}\rangle$, but something in coordinates, like in the case of the quantum mechanical wave-function.

Answer (score 3):

The correct analogy with the QM wave function can be understood from the path integral formulation. Given a theory with an action $S[\varphi]$ the path integral is denoted as
$$
Z = \int [\mathrm{d}\varphi]\,e^{iS[\varphi]}\,.
$$
A wave function*al* is, as the name says, a functional of the configuration variables of your QFT, which obviously are fields. In QM if you had, say, $N$ coordinates, your wave function would be
$$
\psi(q_1,\ldots,q_N)\,.
$$
QFT, on the other hand, can be though of as if there were infinitely many coordinates ($N\to\infty$). Those coordinates describe your field configuration at a certain time slice, which we can take to be $x^0 = 0$ for simplicity. Therefore the wave functional is something like
$$
\Psi[\phi_0(\vec{x})]\,.
$$
You can imagine discretizing your space, at which point the $q_i$'s would be the values of $\varphi$ at the point $x = (0,\vec{x}_i)$.

In the path integral language a field configuration can be thought of as a boundary condition for the integral at a certain time slice. We can therefore define a wave functional as the following path integral
$$
\Psi[\phi_0(\vec{x})] = \int[\mathrm{d}\varphi]_{\varphi(0,\vec{x})\equiv\phi_0(\vec{x})}\,e^{iS[\varphi]}\,.
$$
Where, as you can see, the integration is restricted only to those configurations which have $\varphi(0,\vec{x}) \equiv \phi_0(\vec{x})$. Now, this would actually the vacuum state because we are not inserting anything in the path integral. A more general state can be obtained by putting operators such as
$$
\Psi_{1,\ldots,n}[\phi_0(\vec{x})] = \int[\mathrm{d}\varphi]_{\varphi(0,\vec{x})\equiv\phi_0(\vec{x})}\,\mathcal{O}_1(x_1)\cdots\mathcal{O}_n(x_n)\,e^{iS[\varphi]}\,.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can generally map between second quantization picture (as in QFT) to first quantization (each particle has a coordinate and you get the wave functions). For more than one particle, the QFT version is guaranteed to contain the correct symmetrization or anti-symmetrization of the wave-function.

The wave-function for a two-particle state, for example, is given by
$$ \Phi(r_1, r_2) = \langle r_1, r_2 | a^{\dagger}_p a^{\dagger}_q | {\rm{vac}}\rangle = 
\langle {\rm{vac}}| a(r_2)a(r_1) a^{\dagger}_p a^{\dagger}_q | {\rm{vac}}\rangle$$
where $a(r)$ is the field annihilating a particle at position $r$, which you can get from a Fourier-transform of $a_p$

Comment: By the explicit field configuration for 2 particles I mean something of the form $\phi(x)=\phi_1(x) + \phi_2(x)$. For the harmonic oscillator in QM we have the wave-function of variable x (vector with finite index). No matter what the oscillator excitation state is, it depends just on one vector variable. I want the same thing for quantum fields, i.e., the wave-functional as a map from the field configuration (which is basically a vector with continuous index) to numbers. So no matter how many particles are in the system, I want it still to be a functional of the field configuration.

Comment: And the corresponding field configuration should also be a function of one vector variable: $\phi(x)$, not the 2-particle wave-function $\Phi(x1,x2)$.

Comment: I should rephrase it more explicitly. For QM you give me 3 numbers (coordinates) - I give you the amplitude to find a particle in the designated point in space. For QFT you give me a field configuration (infinite bunch of numbers) - I give you the amplitude to find the field in this configuration. So what this infinite bunch of numbers is for 2-particle state? And how does the corresponding wave-functional which extracts the amplitude looks like?

Comment: You are correct, this is not the right analogy for a wave function*al* in QFT. It is still called a wave function because us physicists are bad at naming things.

Comment: @pgr I'm really not sure that I understand. In QM, only when you have *a one particle problem* your wave function is described by a set of $3$ numbers. When you, for example, solve the Helium-atom problem you have in your Hamiltonian 2 vectors, for the potential $-e^2/|r_1-r_2|$, and the wave-function similarly depends on $6$ coordinates. Basically, in 1st quantization we restrict the number of particles while in 2nd quantization we also quantize it and allow it to change. But for a fixed number of particles the analogy is as I wrote it. Are you interested in a single-particle description?